# SQL Server - why does this query take so long?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
WITH Hierachy 
   ( 
      jobmst_id,  
      jobdep_jobmst,  
      Level 
   ) as  
   (  
   SELECT jobmst_id as dependency,  
      jobdep_jobmst as jobmst_id,  
      0 as Level  
   FROM jobdep m  
   WHERE (m.jobmst_id = '53047') -- insert parameter here

   UNION ALL  
   SELECT m.jobmst_id,  
      m.jobdep_jobmst,  
      ch.Level + 1  
   FROM jobdep m  
   INNER JOIN Hierachy ch  
   ON m.jobmst_id = ch.jobdep_jobmst  
   )  
SELECT jobmst_id AS jobmst_id,  
   jobdep_jobmst AS dependency  
FROM Hierachy  
WHERE Level > 0  
AND Level < 5
```

I ran an estimated execution on it and has a couple of clustered index scans that are taking over 40% each. Is there a better way to write this query?

I basically want to get a hierarchy from the master (`53047`) but only 5 levels deep.

Currently it take about 4 minutes to execute.

Comment: Could you please post your execution plan (xml or text)? What indexes do you have on these tables?

Comment: Did you check `Include Actual Execution Plan (Ctrl+M)` instead of `Display Estimated Execution Plan (Ctrl+L)`?

Comment: This is how you spell hierarchy.

Comment: Also, please post the table definition of `jobdep`, including any keys or indexes.

Comment: The aliases in the anchor part of the cte are a bit misleading, because you name the columns after the declaration of your cte, just so you know :)

Comment: You need a covering index that can be seeked into. e.g. `CREATE INDEX ix ON jobdep(jobmst_id) include(jobdep_jobmst)`

Comment: what are the current table indexes and how much data in the table ?

Comment: also, do you know how many recursion will happen? as you just said you need till 5 level depth, shouldn't you use the recursion hint "OPTION (MAXRECURSION 5)" instead doing all recursions and then filter data ?

Comment: @AnupShah - No. That would terminate with an error (assuming any lower depth items exist at all). It is just a safety feature. This is the correct way to stop recursion at a required depth. It won't carry on recursing unnecessarily.

Comment: @Martin, Here CTE has the column to indicate the Level of recursion for each row in it. in the CTE, the top select is the Anchor Code and the select after Union is the Recursive Code. by the time we do final SELECT from that CTE, the CTE has already done with recursion and what we are doing is just filtering the rows by LEVEL in Select query. I believe the Where filter should be somewhere in the Second Select so that it can stop recursion at certain point if that Point reaches. Check this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885170/how-to-limit-cte-recursion-depth-but-select-generic-table"

Comment: @whoisearth, lets for a while assume "OPTION (MAXRECURSION 5)" is not the option you can use, yet i would suggest replacing "WHERE Level > 0 AND Level < 5" with only "WHERE Level < 5" and moving this condition inside the CTE's Second select statement. I am not saying this will have high performance impact but that seems to me more appropriate way. and then if you give details about indexes/Dtaa volume etc... for table  "jobdep" will be helpful.

Comment: @AnupShah - Agreed. Sorry. What they should do here is add `WHERE ch.Level  < 4` to the recursive part to get the filter pushed down. And remove the `AND Level < 5` from the outer query as now surplus. (4 not 5 as the projected Level is `ch.Level + 1`)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need indexes on jobdep.jobmst_id.

If you have them you should see in the plan index seeks on these 2 indexes. If you have them and do not see seeks on them then you might have a statistics problem. So rebuild statistics or put seek hints on the 2 tables.

Comment: `Hierachy` is a CTE and not a table, so you cannot define any indexes on it.

Answer (score 0):

Performance issues can be very tricky, but using the information available, if you create a index over both columns it will increase the efficiency, since sql server will not need to read the table data-pages from disk. The basic syntax follows:

```
CREATE INDEX jobdep_hierachy ON (jobmst_id, jobdep_jobmst);
```

Please not that the order of the columns matter: the column to be seeked must be appear first on the index.